# How to maintain element position while resizing the viewport

Tags: css, css-position, viewport

I have some divs inside a parent div, which are aligned into this position:

[image: aligned elements]

I set the parent to  `position: relative;` and the children to `position: absolute;`, and just moved the elements bi using `top,left` with `px` values which does brake the position of the elements by resizing the viewport.

How can I retain the element position, while resizing the window?

```css
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    background-color: #cfcfcd;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  
}


/* building the tank  */

.container-border {
    border: 2px solid black;
     height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 20px; 
    /* background-color: white; */


    /* positioning */
    position: relative;

}


.tank {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;

    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}


.pump {
    top: 250px;
    right: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darkgray;
    width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
}


.pipe {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darkgray;
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
    right: 70px;
    top: 210px;

}

.flunsh {
    top: 250px;
    left: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darkgray;
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;

}

.filter {
    top: 270px;
    left: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darkgray;
    width: 150px;
    height: 160px;

}



button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 370px;
    left: 150px;

}
```

```html
 <main>
      <div class="container-border">
        <div class="tank"></div>
        <div class="pipe"></div>
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <div class="flunsh"></div>
        <div class="pump"></div>
        <button type="button">start</button>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: use percentage values

Comment: If possible, you can use a fixed parent container with fixed height width and then position the elements with absolute positioning. That way, even if the viewport size changes, your parent width (or height) will not change, which will mean that the children won't move as well.